# Can I recover data from a clobbered NTFS volume?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery

First of all, yes, I know I'm a moron. Long story short, I overwrote the first few dozen megabytes of a 2 terabyte disk, clobbering the partition table and beginning of an NTFS partition. It's all totally replaceable data, it's just an awful lot, and will be a huge pain in my ass to download over again. Obviously the clobbered data is a lost cause, but I'd like to know if there's any way to partially recover the rest of the data on the old filesystem. I've taken a quick look with the sluethkit and done a bunch of googleling, to no avail. Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's not. This disk has not been reformatted. Save for the first 50 megabytes, the filesystem is totally fine.

Comment: So you've tried the various software and methods mentioned in the answers there? What were the results?

Comment: Bit the bullet and reformatted. Finally completed my complete transition to linux, no more NTFS for me.